# SQL query with left join to get rows in decreasing order from a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have two tables:

**Product**

> productID, productName, productPrice

**Purchased**

> productID, creationDate

Query - return a list of `unique products` that were bought since `June 2nd` with `most expensive product` returned `first`

For this I wrote below query:

```
SELECT Product.productID,
       Product.productName,
       Product.productPrice,
       Purchased.creationDate
FROM   Product
       LEFT JOIN Purchased
              ON Product.productID = Purchased.productID
ORDER BY Product.productPrice DESC
WHERE  Purchased.creationDate > 02 / 06 / 2014
```

Could you please confirm if above written query is correct or I am doing any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.productID, p.productName, p.productPrice, pp.creationDate
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Purchased pp ON p.productID = pp.productID
WHERE pp.creationDate > '2014-06-02'
ORDER BY p.productPrice DESC;
```

Comment: sorry but may I know the difference between my query and yours? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

And make it shorter using `alises`

```
SELECT pr.productID,
       pr.productName,
       pr.productPrice,
       pu.creationDate
FROM   Product pr
       LEFT JOIN Purchased pu
              ON pr.productID = pu.productID
WHERE  pu.creationDate > 02 / 06 / 2014
ORDER  BY pr.productPrice DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a inner join instead of a left join if I do not need to get those products that were never bought at all (Meaning no entry in Pruchased table).  [Joins Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join?answertab=active#tab-top)

and the order by should be the last thing to do.

```
SELECT Product.productID, Product.productName, Product.productPrice, Purchased.creationDate
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Purchased
ON Product.productID=Purchased.productID
WHERE  Purchased.creationDate > '2014-06-02'
ORDER BY Product.productPrice DESC
```